# Stack jpg images from ffmpeg extraction using pipe or any other function?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I extract frames using command

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov" -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 ipcam_%04d.png
```

I tile extracted frames horizontally

```
ffmpeg -i ipcam_73_0001.jpg -i ipcam_73_0002.jpg -filter_complex hstack a.jpg

ffmpeg -i a.jpg -i ipcam_73_0003.jpg -filter_complex hstack a.jpg

ffmpeg -i a.jpg -i ipcam_73_0004.jpg -filter_complex hstack a.jpg
```

.. so on

How do I pipe first `ffmpeg` extraction command and stack the output?

Comment: You will run into image size limits if you try to stack all images.

Comment: Make reasonable assumptions. ok, assume Ill  run for 30 seconds.

Comment: what do you mean by "stack the output" ?

Comment: append the images horizantally. if A1,A2,.... are images extracted from rtsp video,then append horizantally A!,A2,A3..

Answer (score 0):

maybe make a script to stack it? eg

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

function wtf(string $uri, int $seconds = 5): string
{
    $original_working_dir = getcwd();
    $work_dir = $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'wtf');
    unlink($work_dir);
    mkdir($work_dir, 0700);
    chdir($work_dir);
    $cmd = implode(" ", array(
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i " . escapeshellarg($uri),
        "-f image2",
        //"-vf fps=fps=1",
        "-vsync passthrough",
        "-t " . ((int)$seconds),
        "-an",
        "wtf_%04d.png",
    ));
    $out = shell_exec($cmd . " 2>&1");
    $images = glob("*.png");
    //var_dump($images);die();
    natsort($images);
    assert(count($images) >= 2);
    $first = true;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); ++$i) {
        $image = $images[$i];
        $cmd = implode(" ", array(
            "ffmpeg",
            //"-y",
            "-i " . escapeshellarg($image),
            ($i === 0 ? "-i " . escapeshellarg($images[$i + 1]) : "-i a1.jpg"),
            "-filter_complex hstack",
            "a2.jpg"
        ));
        //var_dump($cmd);
        $out = shell_exec($cmd. "2>&1");
        @unlink("a1.jpg");
        // > Output a.jpg same as Input #1 - exiting
        // > FFmpeg cannot edit existing files in-place.
        rename("a2.jpg", "a1.jpg");
        if ($i === 0) {
            ++$i;
        }
    }
    $ret = file_get_contents("a1.jpg");
    var_dump($out, $images, $cmd, $original_working_dir, $work_dir);
    chdir($original_working_dir);
    $cmd_cleanup = "rm -rf " . escapeshellarg($work_dir);
    passthru($cmd_cleanup);
    return $ret;
}

$uri = "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov";
$imageBinary = wtf($uri, 5 * 1);
file_put_contents("a.jpg", $imageBinary);
```

yields:
[image]

(warning though, that

```
    $work_dir = $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'wtf');
    unlink($work_dir);
    mkdir($work_dir, 0700);
```

part technically has a race-condition bug, you could switch it it with some `bin2hex(random_bytes(10))`-scheme instead if that's a concern)